# How to plot height information in Matlab using surf?

Tags: image, matlab, tiff, contour

I have obtained the latitude, longitude and height information from a TIFF image into Matlab and plotting it using the `surfc` function as `surfc(X,Y,Z)`.

`surfc` output:

[image: surfc output]

Image of the tree: 
[image: image of tree]

But how do I get Z to display as a **contour (something like a cone)** corresponding to the *height of an object in the image?*

Thanks for any answers

Comment: Is there height (altitude) information stored for each pixel of the TIFF image? Is the height of the pixel code in the color of each pixel some how? Is there a height information of each tile? Normally there is a single height information for entire image, so you can't use it for display contour.

Comment: Hi, Yes. The height information is stored in the geotiff image itself. I'm using the surf function but all I'm getting is a blank plot with only the coordinates. Actually I wanted to plot the height of a tree contained in the *geotiff* image.

Comment: Could you provide us a [MCVE]

Comment: @Yvon I'm using these two codes. 'surfc(x,y,z);
axis tight'. But after plotting I'm getting a blank plot with the x,y and z. I want the height information to be displayed/plotted corresponding to the height of a tree in the geotiff image

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have  the geotiff image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color mapping of the surf. Example:

```
clear;clc;close all
tif4 = imread('RzwK3.tif');
THeight = rgb2gray(tif4(:,:,1:3));
imshow(THeight)

x = 1:size(THeight,1); % can be changed to coordinates
y = 1:size(THeight,2);
[X,Y] = ndgrid(x,y);

% make contour color on the surface
M = 4; % # color in contour
Cvec = parula(M); % any Mx3 RGB triplet
hs = surf(X,Y,THeight,'EdgeAlpha',.1);
colormap(Cvec)
colorbar
```

If `parula` or other color generation function is not available in your Matlab version, you can assign `Cvec` manually. Each row of the matrix is a RGB color triplet with values between 0 and 1 (you can divide a web RGB color by 256) and there should be `M` rows in the matrix. Example: the following is the output of `parula(4)`, which can be manually input by replacing the line of code.

```
Cvec = [
    0.2081    0.1663    0.5292; % R1 G1 B1
    0.0265    0.6137    0.8135; % R2 G2 B2
    0.6473    0.7456    0.4188; % R3 G3 B3
    0.9763    0.9831    0.0538]; %R4 G4 B4
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is resolved. It was a problem with the Matlab version and I was able to get the correct plot after changing the version. Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the pionts as cartesian coordinates use `plot3`

```
plot3(X,Y,Z,'.');
```

If X and Y are the independent variables and Z the dependent one (The corresponding height for a given X and Y) then use `surf` or `mesh`

```
surf(X,Y,Z);
mesh(X,Y,Z);
```

Otherwise put some sample of your data and results so we can better understand your problem.

**EDIT:** You are actually obtaining a contour plot, but `surfc` should also plot the surface.
Take a look at the [documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surfc.html) of `surfc` and you will see that it combines two plots in one figure (the surface and the contour)

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(30);
figure
surfc(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded the image of my final plot which I'm getting as well as the image of the tree (which is the input file). I'm supposed to get a contour like plot corresponding to the location of the tree which I'm not getting.

Comment: Well, **you are** getting a contour in your plot, but not the plot of the surface. `surfc` is a combination of the `surf` and `contour` in a single plot. Try using only `surf` and only `contour` and see if you get correct results. And post your code. How are you obtaining X,Y and Z from the image?

Comment: `[Z,R] = geotiffread('seewen1.tif');

[X,Y] = pixcenters(R, size(Z));

h = surfc(X,Y,Z); axis tight; 

colorbar()

grid on

hold on` 

I'm using this code to generate. But with only the surf function, I'm getting a blank plot.

Comment: Sorry I don't have the mapping toolbox to reproduce your code. Try running the `surfc` example that I posted in the answer and see if you get the same plot. If you do, then you have to check your X,Y,Z values to make sure are correct

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the same plot with surfc as above example you posted. The dimensions of the image are X:1x1667 double, Y:1x1667 double, Z:1667x1667 single after I extract the image into Matlab.

Comment: X and Y should also be 1667x1667. Use repmat to repeat them `surfc(repmat(X,1667,1),repmat(Y',1,1667),Z)`